# Is there documentation for the vcgencmd pwm_speedup

Tags: raspberry-pi-os

I see that vcgencmd has a command pwm_speedup but I cannot find any documentation on what it does. I assume it speeds up the PWM clock, but I don't want to mess with it unless I know what its doing. Is there any documentation for it?

Comment: I can't find anything either. Perhaps it's a recent addition, and has fallen through the cracks in the RPi documentation (some pretty large cracks there). You should proceed to [the GitHub repo for vcgencmd](https://github.com/raspberrypi/userland/tree/master/host_applications/linux/apps/gencmd), and [submit an issue](https://github.com/raspberrypi/userland/issues) requesting the status & location of the docs for `pwn_speedup`. Please answer your own question here when you learn something.